# Show that $\int_C \vec f \cdot \vec n \, ds =g(\vec r_2)-g(\vec r_1)$

Tags: integration

Let $\vec r_1$ and $\vec r_2$ be two points in $\mathbb{R}^2$ joined by the curve $C$. Let $$\vec f = \left( \frac{\partial g}{\partial y}, -\frac{\partial g}{\partial x} \right)$$

I want to show that $$\int_C \vec f \cdot \vec n \, ds =g(\vec r_2)-g(\vec r_1)$$

I have parametrised $C$ by $\vec r(s)=(x(s),y(s))$ and so from this I have chosen $$\vec n =\left(\frac{dy}{ds}, -\frac{dx}{ds}\right)$$

So I now have $$\int_C \frac{\partial g}{\partial y} dy+\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}dx$$

But I'm not sure what to do from this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** Write your last expression,
$$\int_C \frac{\partial g}{\partial x} dx + \frac{\partial g}{\partial y} dy$$
in terms of vector objects, rather than in explicit coordinates.

> **Additional hint** In particular, write it in terms of the gradient $\nabla g$ of $g$.

Comment: Oh I see. So it becomes $\int_C \nabla g \cdot (dx,dy)$ which gives me the required answer. Thank you!